# Нужно вывести все координаты клеток морского боя с помощью вложенных циклов

Tags: python

Нужно вывести все координаты клеток морского боя с помощью вложенных циклов.

```
А1 А2 А3 А4 А5 А6 А7 А8
Б1 Б2 Б3 Б4 Б5 Б6 Б7 Б8
В1 В2 В3 В4 В5 В6 В7 В7
Г1 Г2 Г3 Г4 Г5 Г6 Г7 Г8
Д1 Д2 Д3 Д4 Д5 Д6 Д7 Д8
Е1 Е2 Е3 Е4 Е5 Е6 Е7 Е8
Ж1 Ж2 Ж3 Ж4 Ж5 Ж6 Ж7 Ж8
З1 З2 З3 З4 З5 З6 З7 З8
```

не пойму как нужно сделать

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: *не пойму как нужно сделать* Ну вроде русским по белому сказано - с помощью вложенных циклов. Вы уж откройте книжку и почитайте хоть что-нибудь про циклы...

Comment: Написал код, если автору вопроса интересно понять, как работает код, то, надеюсь, он его разберёт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример кода, реализующий требования автора вопроса:

```
coords_alf = ['А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ж', 'З']
coords_board = []
for i in range(8):
    coords_board.append([])
    for j in range(1, 9):
        coords_board[i].append(f'{coords_alf[i]}{j}')
        
for row in coords_board:
    print(*row)
```

Вывод:

```
А1 А2 А3 А4 А5 А6 А7 А8
Б1 Б2 Б3 Б4 Б5 Б6 Б7 Б8
В1 В2 В3 В4 В5 В6 В7 В7
Г1 Г2 Г3 Г4 Г5 Г6 Г7 Г8
Д1 Д2 Д3 Д4 Д5 Д6 Д7 Д8
Е1 Е2 Е3 Е4 Е5 Е6 Е7 Е8
Ж1 Ж2 Ж3 Ж4 Ж5 Ж6 Ж7 Ж8
З1 З2 З3 З4 З5 З6 З7 З8
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Alex Не за что)